# RSpec Not Seeing Model Destroy

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

RSpec is not seeing the destruction of the model when I call destroy from the controller. Is there some additional command I need to have in the ProjectsController#destroy method to make rails actually perform the destroy? Or to tell RSpec to reload the Project count after the destroy completes? (Rails 3.2.2)

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @project = current_user.my_projects.find params[:id]
    @project.destroy
  end
end

describe ProjectsController do
  let(:current_user) { Factory(:user) }
  let(:current_user_project) { current_user.my_projects.create(Factory.attributes_for(:project, owner: nil)) }

  context "one of the current users projects" do
    before { delete :destroy, format: :json, id: current_user_project }
    it { response.should be_success }
    it { expect { delete :destroy, format: :json, id: current_user_project }.to change(Project, :count).by(-1) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I remember, in Rails calling destroy only deletes the record in your database and  only freezes your object, meaning you cannot assign values anymore. But it does not actually delete your object. So you have to reload to see your changes.

Comment: How do I reload in the test?